# loading google map from another component with vue router

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vue-router

I have an issue about google map loading. the thing is in #App component reading google map 
component from `<router-view>` but with this way it's giving the error: `"ReferenceError: google is not defined"`. first I thought I am missing something inside `initMap()` but no, because if I try to paste map method into the `app.vue` then google map running without a problem.

By the way my api is inside the `public/index.html`

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API&callback=initMap"></script>
```

the **map.vue** component:

```
<template>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted(){
        this.initMap();
    },
    methods: {
        initMap(){
            let options = {
                center: {lat: 34.693725, lng: 135.502254},
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: "roadmap"
            };

            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

so what do you think problem is and how can I map component work with the `<router-view>`

Comment: cant you just import google from 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API&callback=initMap' in you map.vue?

Comment: nope, this time initMap is not a function error popping up. @user9879287

Answer (score 0):

The [Vue Cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/) has an [example for loading google maps](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/practical-use-of-scoped-slots.html), which uses [google-maps-api-loader](https://github.com/laurencedorman/google-maps-api-loader) to wrap the loading process into a promise.
The promise from the loader is `await`ed in the `mount` hook in the consuming component.

Here's a [codesandbox demonstrating the approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o45zvxk0q).

Comment: Why this might be appropriate, it would be better to include some code and further explanations in your answer, not to just paste links to external pages which might stop working at any point.